# How to get function/symbol information from within a binary file in IOS

Tags: ios, binary, objdump, nm, otool

We have developed a IOS application and found that application binary file is using _malloc() function somewhere inside.

```
$otool -IV Reminders | grep _malloc
0x0000000100415b3a  1436 _malloc
0x0000000100415b40  1437 _malloc_size
$
```

We have not used malloc() function from inside our code. Not sure why this symbol is present within our binary. We would like to understand who is using this malloc() function within our application binary, is it used by some statically linked library or something else ?

Comment: Are you using `Objective-C` in your app? Or have you included libraries/frameworks that use `Objective-C`?

Comment: Add a symbolic breakpoint on `malloc` and run your application.  You'll probably find that **everything** that creates dynamic objects uses it.

Comment: We have used libraries/framework that might have used Objective-C. We didn't use any malloc() function within our code. We are not sure where from it gets included into our binary. Is there any way to figure out from the binary file (using otool, objdump, nm etc) how malloc() is included ?

Comment: did u found solution?

Comment: We have used Xcode debugging tool to identify the issue.